# Being an essential subgroup is hereditary

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

How can I show that the property of being an essential subgroup is transitive?

I know that a subgroup E of an abelian group A is essential if its intersection with any non-zero subgroup of A is non-zero. I tried to reformulate the problem as follows: let E and F be subgroups of A, with E contained in F, if E is essential in F and F is essential in A then E is essential in A. Is it correct?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Take a nontrivial subgroup of $A$; intersect it with $F$; then intersect the result of that with $E$. Is it nontrivial?